# How to open an explorer window to browse a given UNC path using a WPF button or hyperlink?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I have a UNC path like `\\machine\share\folder\something\` and I need to be able to open that location in windows explorer when a button is clicked. What WPF control should I use and how should I bind to that control from my viewModel?

An example of my viewModel is:

```
public class ViewModel : Screen {
    public string LogPath { get { return "\\machine\share\folder\something"; } }
}
```

I'm using Caliburn Micro, but I don't know if that's relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question properly, the use of WPF, Caliburn, etc is fairly irrelevant.  You simply need a function on your ViewModel that runs the following code:

```
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
                      {
                          FileName = "\\\\machine\\share\\folder\\something",
                          UseShellExecute = true
                      });
```

I would use a simple `Button` control with a `Command` that is bound to your ViewModel, and potentially a `CommandArgument` to specify the path to launch if you need to.